# How to implement QR Code Reader in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to integrate QR code Reader in iPhone Application, I have no idea that how to start please any one guide me and give me some link and some sample code for that.

Thanks in Advance:

Comment: What's an "OR" code? Do you mean QR?

Comment: Sorry for mistakes that is QR not OR.

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[iPhone - iOS\]Need QRCode Reader API for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883629/iphone-iosneed-qrcode-reader-api-for-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you google `qr code iPhone open source` , you will find the answer easily.

recommand `ZBar`, which is an open source software suite for reading bar codes from various sources, such as video streams, image files and raw intensity sensors. It supports many popular symbologies (types of bar codes) including EAN-13/UPC-A, UPC-E, EAN-8, Code 128, Code 39, Interleaved 2 of 5 and QR Code.

[official site](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 4):

Before asking a question here, please try to search if there any previous post regarding it.

You can get some of the **free source codes of applications currently available on App store** that are mentioned **[here including a barcode reader - ZBar](http://iphone-development-source-codes.blogspot.in/2012/01/sample-post.html)**. It scans many different barcode formats: EAN-13/UPC-A, UPC-E, EAN-8, Code 128, Code 93, Code 39, Interleaved 2 of 5, DataBar, DataBar Expanded and QR Code.

And, [**ZXing**](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) also works very well. They provided sample apps for iPhone and Android along with it.